# Proving there is no other limit points except $0$ in $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to show the only limit point of the following set is $0$.

$$S = \{1/n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$$

But where I'm at a stand is, the **only** part.

**My attempt**

Assume $\exists x \in S', x \neq 0$.

If $x < 0$, let $\epsilon = |x| $ then $N(x, \epsilon) \cap S = \emptyset$

If $x \in S$, then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $x = 1/n$. Let $\epsilon = |1/n - 1/(n+1)|$, then $N(x, \epsilon) \cap S = \emptyset$

If $x>0, x \notin S$, let $\epsilon = \min \{|s-x| : s \in S \}$, if the minimum exists, then $\epsilon >0$. If $N(x, \epsilon) \cap S \neq \emptyset$, this contradicts $\epsilon = \min $.

But the tricky part is, how to show such $\epsilon$ exists. For example, if $x=0$, such minimum does not exists. I'm not sure there is another point with such properties as $0$, in the case $x>0, x \notin S$.

How can I be sure there is no such point in $x>0, x \notin S$?

Comment: If $x>0, x\notin S$, then consider first (easy) $x \ge 1$. Then consider $\frac1x$ and how it must lie between two consecutive integers, $n$ and $n+1$. Can you find an order relation between $x$ and some values depending on $n$ that help you determing that your $\epsilon$ exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just take $\epsilon =\frac1{2n}$.  Then $B(\frac1n,\epsilon)$ has the property that $B(\frac1n,\epsilon)\cap S$ is finite.

For $x\not\in S$, and $x\not=0$, just let $\epsilon =\frac{\mid x\mid}2$.  Then again the epsilon ball around $x$ has finite intersection with $S$.

To see this, just let $N$ be large enough so that $\frac1N\lt\epsilon $.

Alternatively, no subsequence of $\frac1n$ converges to a different point than $0$, since $\frac1n\to0$.

Comment: Also if $x$ is a limit point of set $S$ then any neighborhood contain infinitly many points...This reduces ur job of arguing shrinking the epsilon ball...provided you already proved this result

Comment: Right.  I was going to stop there.